# android image size from web

Tags: android, height, imageview

I'm trying to support mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi on my current App. The problem is that I'm fetching images from the web (profile pics).  I'm using an imageview with `height = 200dp` the thing is that even tho I have read tons of tutorials and documentation about dp and dpi, I still don't get them.

So my problem is that on an hdpi phone (atrix 2) the image takes about 1/3 of the screen, which is perfect for me.  but on mdpi (galaxy ace) it takes almost 2/3.

What's the best way to set a height for an imageview (from the web, not resources) to support mdpi and hdpi.

thanks

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expositor_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/expositor_info_header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-27dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/misc_placeholder"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

basically my problem is that the 200dp takes different % of screen on mdpi and hdpi

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you are going to want to set a scaleType (try "center_inside") in your xml definition of the ImageView.

If you provide some code (in particular your layout xml file) I might be able to be of more assistance.

**Update**

Now, this may not fully be your problem, but it is a piece of it. DP (or DPI, they are the same thing) adjust for the screen *density* (pixels per inch), not the screen size. That means that an image of 200dp x 200dp will be approximately the same size in inches on both screens, not the same percentage of the screen.

Specs:
Atrix 960 × 540 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Atrix_2#Features)
Galaxy Ace 480 x 320 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Ace)

Since the Atrix is hdpi, and hdpi is a 1.5 multiplier, 200dp will take up 300px in real pixels, or approximately 1/3 (300/960) of the screen as you point out.

On the mdpi Ace, the 200dp translates evenly to 200px, which should be closer to 1/2 the screen. However, with the addition of the actionbar taking up screen real estate, it may seem like more.

The best way to deal with very small screens like the ace... well, my normal solution is to not support them very well, at least not on my first pass, as they are pretty rare. But if you want to, the best way is to provide alternate layouts.

For Example:

Create a folder named layout-large (or similar, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility).

Make a copy of your existing xml file in that folder. (name must be exactly the same)

Modify the file in layout/ so that it works better on smaller screens.

Essentially, if the device has a "large" screen or above (where large is basically the standard these days), it will use the layout in the layout-large/ folder.

Otherwise, it will use the default layout in the layout/ folder.

If you think this explanation is not what is happening, please provide screen shots to verify that the layout is in fact not behaving like it should.